# CakePHP -> HABTM -> controller-view select multiple values and save in correct order into database

Tags: cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I use CakePHP 2.0 and I have two models: `user` and `course`.
They are connected with HABTM, so it is a many-to-many relationship.

I can create, read, update and delete courses, that's all okay.
But now, the user can take part in some courses.

In the add view of the user, I can select many courses with these lines of code, because it creates a multiple select field.

```
$this->set('courses', $this->User->Course->find('list'));
echo $this->Form->input('Course');
```

So I can select multiple values, but the problem is the order! I need a order in my courses, which the user of the application should be able to manage (the start/end date of the course is not relevant).

Example: I have the user with the id = 10.
It should be possible to select no course or 1 or many with a correct order.
I have approx. 200 courses with the IDs 1-200
So it should be possible:

```
* UserId 10 -> no course
* UserId 10 -> CourseId 23
* UserId 10 -> CourseId 23, CourseId 11, CourseId 45, CourseId 10, CourseId 199 (the order is important)
```

How can I do this in my add / edit view and in my controller to handle this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your courses table, you'll have to add another column, let's say related courses.

You shall use this column as a constraint. You can store data either in JSON format or serialized, etc. You can use the data in the column to sort your courses in the find query.

Then, in the view, you must use javascript to restrict the selection of the wrong course and notify the user about the order.

It's just an idea, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Hm, I think I have to add a field in the `course_user` database table to save the order, haven't I? And then I need sth. in the frontend, so the user of the application can select courses to a user and order it. I found this: http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/change-order-multiple-select-lists-using-jquery/ I think this can be what I need. But I do not know how to integrate.